# Can not set a Config value in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, configuration, environment-variables, laravel-8

I'm trying to save site setting variables into the **config/settings.php** file.

```
<?php

return [
    'APP_NAME' => 'example',
    'APP_LOGO' => 'path',
];
```

I can get those values with

1. `config('settings.APP_NAME')` and
2. `\Config::get('settings.APP_NAME')`

But I'm unable to set one using,

1. `config(['settings.APP_NAME' => 'newValue'])` or
2. `\Config::set('settings.APP_NAME', 'newValue')`

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is there any alternative to achieve what I want?

Comment: you can only change in runtime .it wont update to config file

Comment: Then how can I achieve what I want?

Comment: in that case db is better option i guess

Comment: But it will perform a database query every time a request is made? Because the variables are like app_name and app_logo etc.

Comment: you can cache query

Comment: You shouldn't write to the config file directly. If you want to persist data, you should save it to a database. Also, it's ironic to call your file "constants" if you want to store dynamic data.

Comment: @LobsterBaz Please ignore the file name, I was just testing it out.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve that requires you to want to change the config files at runtime?

Comment: @Yinci I want to let the admin change values like signling_url, app_logo, etc.

Comment: How long does a database query take on your system? If that is an issue add SQLite or Redis to store configuration parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config is not designed to be updated on runtime. It's to set fixed server-based settings, like the application name. If you want editable settings, use the database.

- Build yourself a [custom helper](https://www.tutsplanet.com/laravel-8-create-custom-helper-functions/) for a settings wrapper so you can query it like you query the config.
- Migrate yourself a settings table with columns that you wish to edit
- Integrate the values returned from the settings helper into wherever it is you want this to be added
- Set up a form so you can edit these settings as admin and save them to the database

That's it basically. General rule of thumb: is it persistent, use the config. Is is editable, use the database (or some other form of dynamic storage).

Comment: On top of this, I added a cache system as @John Lobo suggested. And it worked as expected.